# How to access to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder ` namespace?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I need the `RequestLocalizationOptions` class. AFAIK it is belongs to  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace.

My application is .NET MAUI + Blazor hybrid.
Initially the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace is unavailable:

> [image]
>
> `Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder'`

Also, looks like no exact matches in NuGet:

[image]

How to get the `RequestLocalizationOptions`?

```cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
  public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
  {
    
    MauiAppBuilder builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    
    builder.
        UseMauiApp<App>().
        ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
          fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        });

    builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
    builder.Services.AddLocalization();
    
    CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = {
      new("en-UK"),
      new("ja-JP")
    };
    
    builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-UK");
      options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
    
    #if DEBUG
      builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
    #endif

    return builder.Build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the Nuget Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization`.

I installed the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization version 2.2.0** in my .net 8.0 maui blazor project. And then I can use the code in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-UK");
      options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });
```

=======================================================

First of all, according to official document about the [RequestLocalizationOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.requestlocalizationoptions?view=aspnetcore-8.0), you should install the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref v8.0.0** package to use it. But I have tested it and found it's incompatible with the Maui project. And you will found this package also uses **Assembly:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.dll**.

And then, accodrding to the official document about [Using the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework):

> With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no longer published to NuGet as packages. Instead, the assemblies are included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework, which is installed with the .NET Core SDK and runtime installers.

But the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` is incompatible with the ios and mac platform when I added it in the .net 8 maui blazor project.

So, there is no better choice but you can report it on the Maui or AspNetCore repo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but this package [has been deprecated](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217). It should be another way to get the `RequestLocalizationOptions` and `RequestCulture`...

Comment: O'K, I have accepted your answer!