# How to obligate to initialize the property inside the inherited record via property initializer?

Tags: c#

I want `heading` property be initialized *inside* inherited record, but via **property initializer**, not via constructor or object initializer:

```cs
internal abstract record TaskManagerLocalization
{
  
  internal string heading { get; init; }
  
}

internal record TaskManagerJapaneseLocalization : TaskManagerLocalization
{
  
  internal string heading { get; init; } = "タスクマネージャー";
  
}
```

Currently, we can omit the initializing of `heading` and C# will not consider it as the error:

```cs
internal record TaskManagerJapaneseLocalization : TaskManagerLocalization
{
  
  internal string heading { get; init; };
  
}
```

It is not fine for my case because `TaskManagerLocalization` must obligate the inheritor to initialize this property via property initializer.

In the TypeScript language, the solution will be:

```js
abstract class TaskManagerLocalization
{
  
  public abstract readonly heading: string;
  
}


abstract class TaskManagerJapaneseLocalization  extends TaskManagerLocalization
{
  
  public readonly heading: string = "タスクマネージャー";
  
}
```

Well, `TaskManagerLocalization` does not obligate the inheritors to initialize the `heading` via field initializer, but if we will remove the field initializer, the error `Property 'heading' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)` will occur. However, because there is no constructor initializing the `heading` property, the only way to do is initialize it via field initializer.

Equivalent for C# and records?

Comment: Why do you care _how_ it is initialized?

Comment: "Why do you care how it is initialized?" - Because according to the idea `TaskManagerJapaneseLocalization` must not accept the data from the outside.

Comment: "Outside" as in "anything but the inheritor itself"?

Comment: Btw: I have the suspicion this is actually an x-y question since you are seemingly trying to implement localization for which there are idiomatic solutions for quite any UI tech.

Comment: @Fildor ""Outside" as in "anything but the inheritor itself"? - Yes. "...for which there are idiomatic solutions for quite any UI tech"  - It is [not everything fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77696111/4818123) with idiomatic solutions.

Comment: Then maybe have a brief mention of your problem with the idiomatic solution in the question or you will argue more about not using it than solving your specific problem.

Comment: So, I figure you are using Blazor/Maui and your attempt to use the idiomatic localization failed because of compatibility issues with Mac/iOS ? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same, just make the property abstract, and remove the init accessor, then the inheritors must define and initialize it.

```
internal abstract record TaskManagerLocalization
{
    internal abstract string heading { get; }
}

internal record TaskManagerJapaneseLocalization : TaskManagerLocalization
{
    internal override string heading { get; } = "タスクマネージャー";
    
    // To avoid generating a backing field
    //internal override string heading => "タスクマネージャー";
}
```